# Can't convert string to Date object

Tags: swift

I have a date string generated from a `UIDatePicker`, after the user chooses a date from the picker, the date is converted to a string and shown in the `UITextField` I have a button, that when is clicked, I want to check if the Start date is more recent than the End date, which in that case to show an alert with error.
The problem is, I can't convert my date string to a date object.

This is my code:

```
internal func handleSubmit() {
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = MY_DATE_FORMAT
    guard let startString = self.mView.startDateTextField.text else { return }
    guard let endString = self.mView.endDateTextField.text else { return }

    guard let start = dateFormatter.date(from: startString) else { return } //<--- Returns here
    guard let end = dateFormatter.date(from: endString) else { return }

    if checkDate(startDate: start, endDate: end) {
        //TODO: This is ok, move the another screen.
    }else {
        //TODO: Show error.
    }
}
```

`MY_DATE_FORMAT` is a simple string `"dd MM yyyy"`

The reason I don't take the date straight from the UIDatePicker is that I would need to check if I'm using the `Start or End UITextField` and I don't really want to put an if statement inside the valueDidChange method I have for the DatePicker, so I thought about convertring the string back to date.

The string shows like "July 19, 2019" and I guess 'July' is the problem but I can't really tell as I'm relativly new to Swift.

Comment: Why don’t you use the same DateFormatter you use when converting the date picker date to a string in the first place?

Comment: Wouldn't parsing the string back to a date object be more expensive than just checking?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson It is the  same Dateformatter.

Comment: @RenzoTissoni I guess, but I thought about, if I put the if statment there, it will solve the problem, but will run each time valueChanged happens in the UIDatePicker, won't it?

Comment: I think you are to concerned with this `if` and are making things harder for yourself for no good reason. I think you should skip the conversion step and use the dates directly